# get user role. parameter id return type string

Tags: php

```
function user_role_parameter($user_id){
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE user_id = $user_id ";
    $the_user_id = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($the_user_id)){
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $user_role = $row['user_role'];
    }
    if($user_id > 0) {
       return $user_role;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Please take time to format your code and explain your question better, it will help you get a better response.

Comment: You should not be using `mysqli_query()` etc. directly in WordPress. There are APIs for getting this sort of thing. You should also check the database that you're querying. There is no `user_role` column.

Answer (score 1):

You should use WordPress functions to get the user role by user id. Please try code given below:

```
function user_role_parameter($user_id)
{
    $user_meta = get_userdata($user_id);

    if ( !empty($user_meta) ) {
        $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;
        $user_role = '';
        foreach( $user_roles as $role ){
            $user_role .= $role . ', ';
        }
        return $user_role;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```